# Function prototype path

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Why the third expression is false?
Second and third aren't the same?

```
'use strict'
function func () {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(func) === Function.prototype) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(func)) === Object.prototype) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.prototype) // false
```

Comment: Because that's not how the language was designed? I get that it's not a very *satisfying* answer, but I'm not sure what you're after here. The only way those two would be equivalent was if `Function` was created by calling `new Object()`, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

All functions return a prototype. Prototypes are the mechanism by which JavaScript objects inherit features from one another, not an instance of the prototype of that object. so in that third example it returns that.  To clarity let's just log those:

```js
'use strict'

function func() {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(func) === Function.prototype) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(func)) === Object.prototype) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.prototype) // false


console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(func))); // logs {}
console.log(func); // logs function func() {}
console.log("PT:", func.prototype); // logs - PT: {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)); // = a function "function () { [native code] }"

console.log(Object.prototype); // {} = and object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is actually is func.__proto__ === Function.prototype    
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(func) === Function.prototype)
// func.__proto__.__proto__ (actually Function.prototype.__proto__) === Object.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(func)) === 
Object.prototype)
// Function.__proto__ !== Object.prototype, but rather Function.__proto__ 
// === Object.__proto__ and further more === Number.__proto__ === Whatever.__proto__
// because they are constructors, not instances of an object
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) !== Object.prototype)
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))
console.log(Function.__proto__ === Object.__proto__)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).